# How to install Cat UI for LOVE in Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to make an application with Lua, LOVE and CatUI which I found CatUI before on [here](https://github.com/love2d-community/awesome-love2d?tab=readme-ov-file#ui).
I couldn't found any websites or even their own GitHub page for an installation guide to CatUI.

I tried reaching to their GitHub page. I tried asking ChatGPT, while trying to install it on my OS which is windows by downloading its repository.

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: The CatUI github has an example. It starts with `require "catui"`, that should give you a hint. You need to take the catui folder from the github download and copy the whole folder to the same directory as Lua file, or somewhere where `require` will find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are need to run the luarock for it: https://luarocks.org/